# Using localStorage in webapp

Tags: jquery, web-applications, local-storage

I've some questions to use the localStorage object in a jquery mobile webapp:
I have two apps and in both I want to handle some settings. For example app 1 saves a value like this:

```
localStorage.setItem("example", "one");
```

And app 2 save the same attribute but with another value:

```
localStorage.setItem("example", "two");
```

What happens if I then read the settings with getItem? Does any app has it's own storage or can app 1 read the settings of app 2?

If I remove a webapp later (delete the bookmark on home screen), will then the data of the localStorage also be removed or is it necessary to manually clear the browser cache (for example under settings > safari)?

What is the difference between localStorage and cookies?

What is the difference between localStorage.setItem() and window.localStorage.setItem()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage is per domain.  so www.foo.com does not share any data with www.bar.com.  They each get their own localStorage.  If you do have two apps on the same domain, but at different paths, then you should be concerned about key conflicts.  Consider using [store.js](https://github.com/nbubna/store), as it has a namespace feature to make it easy to avoid conflicts:

```
var settings = store.namespace('app1');
settings('example', 'one'); // will automatically store as 'app1.example'
```

Cookies are different in that they do respect paths, but they also are sent along with every single http request (higher bandwidth costs) and are usually limited to a few kilobytes, whereas localStorage usually has multiple megabytes of space.

Comment: Oh, and there's no difference between window.localStorage.setItem and localStorage.setItem. They're exactly the same.